# How can I customize the way my taxonomy terms are displaying?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have been searching all over the place for some help on this.

I currently have my tags displaying for each node like such: tag,tag,tag

Now I would like them to display a little cleaner and more appealing to my visitors. So what I would like to do is have them display like such: tag \ tag \ tag

Now from what I have read, I need to target the field API? and use a preprocess function to alter what the array is spiting out? Please correct me if I am wrong.

This seems like an easy task to complete but I just can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a preprocess function is what you're looking for, I suspect in D7 this will help:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
if(arg(0)=='node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    $results = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);
    if(is_array($results)) {
        foreach ($results as $item) {
```

In terms of D6, node-taxonomy.tpl.php and page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out... but in your example I don't see here the \ symbol comes into play... i'm still a little lost and yes I am in D7. Again thanks for the response!

Comment: The sample I provided is incomplete PHP code. The addition of the '/' character would be in the foreach loop as you see fit. $item is would each of the terms to something like: 

$categories .= $item .' / ';

Perhaps you might want to investigate basic PHP programming concepts first? It will be essential to customizing Drupal.

Comment: @DeeZone... great thanks for the added explanation.